# replaceAll error

Tags: java, regex

This is my regex. I want to find the opening and closing parentheses and replace them with "\(" and "\)".

```
word = word.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("("), "\\" + "(").replaceAll(Pattern.quote(")"), "\\" + ")");
```

This is the output if word = "word)":

```
New word is: word)
```

As you can see it didn't change a thing.

Comment: Why do you need to use regular expressions for a simple replacement like this? Just use the normal replace function and spare yourself some trouble: `word.replace("(", "\\" + "(").replace(")", "\\" + ")");`

Comment: Thank you it worked. You can put this in answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `\\\\` like this :

```
word = word.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("("), "\\\\" + "(")
        .replaceAll(Pattern.quote(")"), "\\\\" + ")");
```

or without `Pattern.quote` :

```
word = word.replaceAll("\\(", "\\\\(").replaceAll("\\)", "\\\\)");
```

or instead in your case you can just use replace :

```
word = word.replace("(", "\\(").replace(")", "\\)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Two answers worked:

```
word.replace("(", "\\" + "(").replace(")", "\\" + ")"); – OH GOD SPIDERS
```

and

```
replacing \\ with \\\\ in the replaceAll - YCF_L.
```